# Ajax request shows complete but data not submitted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple modal window containing an input field. I am using jquery ajax to validate as well as submit data to database using php. The ajax request shows status code 200 ok but data doesnt get inserted and no success function executes. Does anyone notice any error? Need help

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#add_location").click(function() {

                var inputDiv = $('#inputDiv').val();
                var dataString = 'location=' + inputDiv;

                if (inputDiv == '') {
                $('#error_message').html("Please enter a location");
            } else {
                $.ajax
            ({
              type: "POST",
              url: "add_location.php",
              data: dataString,

              success: function(data)
              {
                        $("#error_message").empty();
                        $("#error_message").html(data);
              }
              });

            }
            return false;
                });
            });


</script>
```

add_location.php

```
<?php

$location = new dbhandler();



$ran_id = mt_rand(45287,98758);

if(isset($_POST)) {

$locationData = $_POST['location'];

  try{
    $location->create('shop_locations', array(
      'r_id' => $ran_id,

      'location' => $locationData,
    ));
    echo "Location successfully added";
  }catch(Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

create() is a method for inserting data

```
create($tableName, $fields = array());
```

Comment: Are you getting data in your php file after posting ?

Comment: I dont know. Is there way to see the posted values?

Comment: echo your $locationData, check you are getting anything or not.

Comment: @Amir it shows empty

Comment: Can you check your network tab in the browser, there should be a message

Answer (score 0):

You can try something

```
   //js file
   $.ajax({
        url: "You_url",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#form_name").serialize(),
        headers: {
            'Authorization' : 'JWT ' + token
        }
    })
    .done(function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

And echo post data in php file if you get anything. I was using JWT so I have used JWT here and token is the variable where I am storing my token

Comment: I used this 
`$.ajax
      ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_location.php",
        data: $("#locationForm").serialize(),
    });
     .done(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
       });
       .fail(function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        });`

It's showing undefined token

Comment: getting anything on done or error section or in network tab of the borwser ?

Comment: Nothing on the network tab but on the console i am getting an error message. Undefined token

Comment: try changing content-type to application/json like this

content-type: "application/json",

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle somewhere, so I can check your code thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring the wrong the DOM *id*. You probably have this formation.

```
<div id="inputDiv">
Location <input type="text" id="myInput"><br>
</div>
```

In this case `inputDiv = $('#inputDiv').val()` will be different with `inputDiv = $('#myInput').val()`